# Adjusting dict values from another script on the fly

Tags: python

I have an automation script containing objects with different dict values (file paths)

From another script I need to take these values and amend the file path depending on the system OS. What I want is to iterate over my list of variables and amend the file path.

For example:

```
varA = {"source": "arc:/resources/folder/image.png"}
```

I need this to be converted to ...

```
varA = {"source": "users/charrison/desktop/folder/image.png"}
```

So I need to iterate over my variable script changing just the beginning of the path name. Replace 'arc:/resources' with 'users/charrison/desktop'. Im using an automation software which collates all objects into one global script whilst my code is in another

Please help

Answer (score 0):

```py
for k in varA:
   varA[k].replace("arc:/resources", "users/charrison/desktop")
```

Comment: Thank you - that's very helpful but could you tell me, if I have hundreds of variables in my script, only some of which have the "source" dict attribute ... how this will work? So Id like to iterate over all variables in my one script, whichever contains the arc:resources ... change to users/charrison. varA is just an example of one of hundreds